# In Pyramid can you have an ACL on both a class and an instance of that class

Tags: security, sqlalchemy, acl, pyramid

In a pyramid app, I have some resource objects that are also SQLAlchemy ORM objects. For these objects I need to express some permissions at the type-level (ie at the class level), for which one might normally do something like this (specifying acl as a class field):

```
class MyModelClass(Base):
  __acl__ = []
```

However, I also have some permissions whose content needs to be computed at run-time, after the ORM class is loaded, for which one might normally do this (specifying acl as a callable on the instance):

```
class MyModelClass(Base):
    def __acl__(self):
      return my_dynamic_acl
```

My problem is that I'd like to do *both of these things* for the same class, is this possible?  If I mix the two above as is, the callable hides the class field, so that won't work.

The reason I want to have permissions specified at both the class and instance level is that I have some operations (such as "new") that won't have access to a model object, and thus the corresponding route factory will be supplying the **class** of MyObject (and the class level **acl** is the one I want to have in effect); and I have other operations that do operate on an instance of MyObject (and these need to be computed dynamically and thus can't be declared in the class field **acl**) and for these I will have the route factory return an **instance** of MyObject, and in this case I want pyramid to see the **acl** that's created on the instance.

Michael

Comment: Do you want a union of both the instance and class level permissions on instances?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to merge the default acls with your dynamic acls manually. This requires a bit more frameworking in your code to get working but isn't too hard.

```
class MyModelClass(Base):
    __default_acl__ = []
    __acl__ = __default_acl__  # helpful if you're doing this on a base class

    def __acl__(self):  # overrides the base class' __acl__ attribute with a dynamic one
        dynamic_acl = []
        return self.__default_acl__ + dynamic_acl
```